# SimpleDraweeView rounded inside scrollview

Tags: android, fresco

I'm trying to migrate from UIL to Facebook's Fresco lib. So far everything looks fine but when I put a rounded image inside an scrollview I get a weird behaviour: While scrolling to the bottom, the image overlaps the action bar and it keeps there when I go up.

[image: Screenshot]

this is my code:

```
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/img_item_detail_avatar"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/icn_avatar_mini"
                fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1" />
```

Also, I'm experiencing the same behaviour inside ListViews. Have you had a similar issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Fresco actually recommends against using ScrollViews: http://frescolib.org/docs/gotchas.html#don-t-use-scrollviews

That being said, this may be a bug. Please file a GitHub issue: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/new. We'll need to see a bit more of the calling code to have an idea what is happening.

Comment: @tyronen I'm facing the same problem with ListViews so I think that is an ActionBar related issue. I've already opened an issue on github but I haven't got any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of weeks, I was able to solve this issue! I've changed my ActionBar to [android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) and now it works great!